# Where are questions on specific SQL code on-topic?

Tags: discussion

It seems that in some ways there is a certain overlap regarding questions over code. For example my recent question over on stackoverflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932853/sql-conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-data-type-int)

However, there are also very similar questions on this site, [such as this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78235/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-data-type-int-in-sql-serv)

While I am not a longtime user and do not known the history of this stack, It seems that at some point this grey area will need to be addressed, else it will surely lead to multiple copies of a question with possibly the best answer not available to those on a specific site.